# Compiler issue on UNIX

Tags: unix

I want to know whether cc compiler is installed or not on my Solaris machine.
After searching on net I came to know that if following three packages are installed then cc compiler should exist:
SUNWscpu
SUNWbtool
SPROcc

All the above packages I have verified by running the command pkginfo.

When I am running cc command ,I am getting the following error:
/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed

Also I have tried to look into cc file".
First it is checking whether "/usr/ccs/bin/ucbcc" exist or not(in my case not exist),otherwise it is throwing the above error.

Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created the soft link  /usr/ccs/bin/ucbcc to /opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc
Then it worked.